# Using for loop to make a Loading... animation

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

so I am making a BMI calculator in C but am trying to make it more fun and have a bit of extra character by making it seem a bit more like a program. One of the features I have been trying to implement is to make an animation that says something like Loading... where the "..." appear one second at a time as to simulate something that actually is loading. I have come up with something like this:

```
printf("Loading");
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
{   
    printf(".");
    sleep(1);
}
```

However this doesn't work at all since all it prints out is Loading, then the "..." and whatever comes up next in the program.
I have been able to make it work if inside the printf in the loop i put \n as in

```
printf("Loading");
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
{   
    printf(".\n");
    sleep(1);
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this might be happening will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: thats because `stdout` is buffered. the `\n` also signals a buffer flush.
You need to flush the buffer after every iteration.
Try `fflush(NULL)` or `fflush(stdout)`

Comment: @Raildex `\n` does not necessarily signal a buffer flush, but it's common that the terminal flush the buffer on newline. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\b` backspace. You might also have to ensure that the console get flushed after each print, because normally that only happens when `\n` is encountered.

Here's a horrible loading screen simulator for Windows:

(Only `Sleep` is Windows-specific, the rest is standard C.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main (void)
{
  printf("Loading"); fflush(stdout);
  
  for(;;)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
      printf("."); fflush(stdout); 
      Sleep(300);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
      printf("\b \b"); fflush(stdout);
      Sleep(300);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

`\b \b` goes back one character, prints a space which moves forward 1 position yet again, which the second `\b` counters.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```c
printf("Loading");
fflush(stdout);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    putchar('.');
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
}
putchar('\n');
```

`sleep()` is part of `unistd.h` Unix library.